# Naming date ranges returns NAs with cut&label approach

Tags: r, date

I am trying to create variable that indicates the market sentiment for different date ranges in my data set. Those are the date ranges which I would like to have in a dedicated column `tripsentiment$sentiment`:

[image]

My approach was the following code since I did not manage to use ifelse for different categories and could not find a better solution:

```
tripsentiment$sentiment <- cut.POSIXt(tripsentiment$date,
                             breaks = as.POSIXct(as.Date(c("10-03-2016", "13-06-2016",
                                                           "16-07-2017", "01-09-2017",
                                                           "14-09-2017", "13-01-2018",
                                                           "01-04-2018", "05-05-2018",
                                                           "02-04-2019"))),
                             labels = c("BULL", "BEAR", "BULL", "BEAR", "BULL", "BEAR", 
                             "BULL", "BEAR"))





      ethamount                date              dollvalue    id ispurchase            dollarcum    purchcost  ROI sentiment
1  8.7796312554873e-5 2016-03-11 01:00:00 -0.0010491659350307322   883          1                    0 1.049166e-03  0.0      <NA>
2               0.001 2016-03-18 01:00:00  -0.010740000000000001 36927          1                    0 1.074000e-02  0.0      <NA>
3             75.4154 2016-03-25 01:00:00            -804.682318  2637          1                    0 8.046823e+02  0.0      <NA>
4 0.10662867986198896 2016-05-02 02:00:00    -1.0662867986198896 72274          1                    0 1.066287e+00  0.0      <NA>
5                0.01 2016-05-02 02:00:00                   -0.1 94359          1 0.010899999999999993 1.000000e-01 10.9      <NA>
6                 0.1 2016-05-04 02:00:00    -0.9460000000000002  3083          1                    0 9.460000e-01  0.0      <NA>
```

However the result is a column of NAs and I can simply not figure out why.

dput output looks as follows:

```
 structure(list(ethamount = c("8.7796312554873e-5", "0.001", "75.4154", 
"0.10662867986198896", "0.01", "0.1"), date = structure(c(1457654400, 
1458259200, 1458864000, 1462147200, 1462147200, 1462320000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), dollvalue = c("-0.0010491659350307322", "-0.010740000000000001", 
"-804.682318", "-1.0662867986198896", "-0.1", "-0.9460000000000002"
), id = c("883", "36927", "2637", "72274", "94359", "3083"), 
    ispurchase = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), dollarcum = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0.010899999999999993", "0"), purchcost = c(0.00104916593503073, 
    0.01074, 804.682318, 1.06628679861989, 0.1, 0.946), ROI = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 10.9, 0), sentiment = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I assume it is some sort of formatting issue with as.date but I can not quiet figure it out, therefore I ask for help here and appreciate every hint.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(tripsentiment))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as.Date` requires `format` argument if it is not in the default format `%Y-%m-%d`.  Here, the format is `%d-%m-%Y`

```
brks <- as.Date(c("10-03-2016", "13-06-2016",
                                                            "16-07-2017", "01-09-2017",
                                                            "14-09-2017", "13-01-2018",
                                                            "01-04-2018", "05-05-2018",
                                                            "02-04-2019"), format = '%d-%m-%Y')
```

-output

```
> brks
[1] "2016-03-10" "2016-06-13" "2017-07-16" "2017-09-01" "2017-09-14" "2018-01-13" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-05" "2019-04-02"
> cut(tripsentiment$date, breaks = as.POSIXct(brks), labels = c("BULL", "BEAR", "BULL", "BEAR", "BULL", "BEAR", 
                             "BULL", "BEAR"))
[1] BULL BULL BULL BULL BULL BULL
Levels: BULL BEAR
```